# Navbar gets ruined after calling ajax to inlay a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html page that displays admin links in nav bar as given:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a id = "addUserAnchor" onclick="loadDoc()">Add User</a></li>
                <li><a href="viewUser">View User</a></li>
                <li><a href="countUser">Count Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="addTrain.html">Add Train</a></li>
                <li><a href="viewTrain">View Train</a></li>
                <li><a href="countTrains">Count Trains</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle" href="logout" aria-expanded="false" >Sign out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav><!-- /.navbar -->
```

I am also calling ajax to display each of the links given within the page itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function loadDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "addUser.html", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

But once I click the Add User link, the navbar alignment gets ruined.
I have attached before and after pics for reference

---

Before clicking on the link
[image: Before clicking on the link]

After Clicking link
[image: After Clicking link]

Comment: My best bet is that you load some sort of style in that gets mixed up, but can't say for sure without seeing what your `this.responseText` looks like.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes... I got bootstrap 4 in `this.responseText` and 3 in the current that got mixed up. Is there any way to load the file without affecting eachother's css?